# How would I delete any "word" that includes dashes in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array that contains data, so it'll be like:

```
array(27.42, 27.71, 26.61, 204.12 1995-1-17)
```

And I want to remove all words with dashes so that I'm left with an array that looks like:

```
array(27.42, 27.71, 26.61, 204.12)
```

Here's a picture of the exact array.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRPDt.png

Do I use regex? What is the best method. I tried using an if function to replace all words that include "-" with " ", but it didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `^.*-.*$` matches the string which has `-` hyphens.

Comment: It gives me an error that there's no delimiter. :/

Comment: `"~^.*-.*$~"` like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My try :

```
<?php
$value = array(27.42, 27.71, 26.61, '204.12 1995-1-17');

$pattern = '/\s*\b\w*\-\w*\b/';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $value);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $index=>$value)
{
 if (strstr($value,'-')) 
 {
  $ex=explode(" ",$value,2);
  $array[$index]=@$ex[0];
 }
}
```

Simply walk through the array and check if the value contains dash ...
Please note the foreach is associative, so you will get the index of the value inside the array, this is why you can unset it.

Comment: I tried it but it looks like it deleted the whole element?

Comment: yes, first it did, now i've updated the code to cut the content by the space, and return the first part.

Comment: Oddly enough this works in a fiddle, but it doesn't work in my real code. Hmm. Thanks though.

Comment: haven't you forget to change $array in the second occurence as well to your $variable ?!
you must change at the foreach($array and the $array[$index] as well ...